# Can you substract business expenses that increases good will?

Tags: taxes, canada, business

Can you subtract business expenses that increases good will? Can you gain a tax advantage if you spend money to make a non-profit product that may increase good will for your company? Let's say you're adding a mod to a game that's free and the mod adds a reference to one of your products as indirect as it may be, could it still be considered to be a business expense that will allow you to gain a tax advantage? Does the law differ in Canada from the United States?

Comment: There are special rules in business expense recognition for non-profit contributions, for research and development, for intellectual property generation, etc. Your examples seem to fall along these lines.

Comment: Can you tie this to personal finance? Questions about accounting are off-topic on this site unless they are related to personal finance.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/146606/30539

Comment: You seem to have deep misunderstanding of "goodwill". Goodwill arsises only from offered or actual aquisitions between companies. You can't just spending money to create goodwill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the mod adds a reference to one of your products

That provides a clear benefit to your company so you could deduct it as a business expense. Good will doesn't matter.